# Can I do this in Multisim?

Tags: multisim, sequential-logic

Here is sequential circuit I want to simulate in Multisim:

[image]

Pay attention to AND gates which I labeled with red numbers.
Inputs to first gate are X and Q1, to second X and Q2 and to third X and complemented Q1. To simulate this circuit, I would connect all those flipflop outputs (Q1, Q2 and complemented Q1) to and gates.
Question: Is it possible to label Q1, Q2 and complemented Q1 like on schematic I posted on some way so they represent Q1, Q2 and Q1_complement outputs of flipflops, WITHOUT CONNECTING THEM WITH WIRES?
Why I ask this? Imagine we have some really complicated schematic. It would be very time consuming drawing that schematic in Multisim and, moreover, schematic would be very confusing with all that wires...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click on any wire in Multisim and you can go to Properties and edit the net name. For any serious design schematic I recommend setting net names for everything. It makes discussion and diagnostics much easier later. Also much easier later when you're doing PCB layout in Ultiboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you must label the wires at the outputs of the flip-flops as well. In general, simulators will implicitly connect any wires that have the same name. However, connecting a wire to a pin will not automatically give it a name like `Q2`...you must explicitly add that name to all wire segments that you want to connect.